# NumPy inheriting: losing attributes in custom class instance when changing datatype

Tags: python, numpy, inheritance, instance, metaprogramming

Is there some more **generic** and in general **best practice** to deal with a problem when numpy changing datatype results in loss of instance attributes?

(MyCustomClass inherits from np.ndarray)

**Problem**:

```
array = MyCustomClass(shape=[4,4,4],dtype=np.float16)
array.variable = 5
array_uint8 = np.uint8(array)
print(array_uint8.variable)
>> AttributeError: 'MyCustomClass' object has no attribute 'variable'
```

**Note**, that changing datatype doesnt result in changing array's class, which is MyCustomClass

**My very bad solution**

```
class uint8(np.uint8):
    def __new__(cls,*args, **kwargs):
        instance = super().__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
        print('instance class', instance.__class__)

        # Moving attributes from one instance to another
        instance.__dict__ = args[0].__dict__ # args[0] is MyCustomClass instance
        return instance

>>> instance class <class '__main__.MyCustomClass'>
```

I would prefer a solution that would work in such a way, that I wouldn't have to modify np.uint8 (or other numpy classes) at all.

Comment: Does `array.astype('uint8')` still have this problem?

Comment: Yes. It still persist

Comment: How did you subclass `ndarray`? Did you define `__new__()` and `__array)finalize__()` and generally follow the advice [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.subclassing.html)? (I'm only asking because inheriting from `ndarray` is unlike most other libraries.)

Comment: You created a new array based on your constructor. `variable` was something you added to the instance dict. It wouldn't show up if it wasn't in init.

Comment: @kwinkunks it was as you pointed out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @kwinkunks I was able to find solution.

As @kwinkunks pointed out, it is necessary to define **__array_finalize__**.
Inside it, it is possible to exchange **__dict__**'s between obj's -> self represents new array and obj represents old one

```
class MyCustomClass(np.ndarray):

    def __array_finalize__(self, obj):
        if isinstance(obj, (MyCustomClass,)):
            self.__dict__ = obj.__dict__
```